# GeoPoint class not found in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gps

How we can use the `Geopoint` in android Studio? I am using the `Geopoint` class in my Eclipse project,now I am trying to convert this into the Android Studio project i have converted almost it but there `'Geopoint' are't resolved a type`.

Comment: Is there a library you are not importing? Libraries are imported differently in Android Studio compared to Eclipse.

Comment: I am useing google-play-services_lib but getting Geopoint' are't resolved a type.

Comment: Find what library the GeoPoint class is from and list that as a dependency of your module in its build.gradle file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am useing google-play-services_lib but getting Geopoint' are't resolved a type.

`GeoPoint` is not used by Google Play Services. It does not exist in the Maps V2 API or in the Android SDK.

There *was* a `GeoPoint` class in the Maps V1 SDK. That SDK was deprecated ~18 months ago and you can no longer get API keys for it.

Make sure that the code that you are trying to use is for Maps V2. If you are trying to use `GeoPoint` for something independent of either map API, you will need to write your own `GeoPoint` class.